# Why exists a periodic point?

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

In Brin's book "Introduction to dynamical systems", page 10, he defines a cuadratic function $q_\mu$ for $\mu>4$. He observes that $[\frac{1}{\mu}, \frac{1}{2}] \subset q_{\mu}^2([\frac{1}{\mu}, \frac{1}{2}])$ and then he says that by the intermediate value theorem, exists a fixed point of $q_{\mu}^2$, but I don't have any idea about why this is true. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $q_\mu^2$ attains its maximum on $[1/\mu,1/2]$ at some point of $x_M\in[1/\mu,1/2]$ and its minimum on $[1/\mu,1/2]$ at some point $x_m\in[1/\mu,1/2]$.

Since $[1/\mu,1/2]\subset q_\mu^2([1/\mu,1/2])$, then $q_\mu^2(x_M)-x_M\geq1/2-x_M\geq0$ and $q_\mu^2(x_m)-x_m\leq1/\mu-x_m\leq0$.

Therefore $q_\mu^2(x)-x$ vanishes at some point of $[1/\mu,1/2]$.

Comment: why $q_{\mu}^2(x_M) \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @HeMan $q_\mu^2([1/\mu,1/2])$ is connected, for being the continuous image of an interval. In particular, it is a closed interval itself. Since it contains $[1/\mu,1/2]$, then the maximum of that interval is not smaller than $1/2$, and the minimum not larger than $1/\mu$.